# How to select ALL matching results of a filter in a document library (not just those displayed on the user's screen)?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, filter

**Desired Behaviour**

- Filter items in a `Document Library` by `Column` title
- Click `Select All` icon
- ALL items that match the filter are selected (not just those displayed on the user's screen)

The desired functionality is demonstrated in GMail when performing a search and clicking `Select All`, ie:

[image]

**Actual Behaviour**

It seems document libraries use 'lazy load' functionality where only enough items are retrieved to fill the user's screen.

For example, if I were to apply the following filter on a Column title:

```
Vehicle Type:  Boat
```

It might display 100 items.

If I then clicked `Select All`, the interface would say `100 selected`, even though there could be 5,000 results, eg:

[image]

[image]

**Workaround**

Currently I am instructing users to:

> Keep scrolling until items don't load anymore to ensure all matching documents in the library are loaded and selected

But this is not a scalable or sophisticated solution.

**Question**

Is there a way to select ALL matching results of a filter in a document library, rather than just those displayed on the user's screen?

**Environment**

Browser: Chrome Version 91.0.4472.101 (Official Build) (64-bit)
SharePoint Online
Microsoft Team SharePoint Site Document Library

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed this in my own environment.  The way to get the behavior you desire is to do these two things:

1. Ensure that the column(s) being filtered on are *indexed columns*
2. To index a column got to **Library Settings --> Columns** section
   see Image 1 below
3. Here is the magic:  go into the view's edit screen and *explicitly set* the view's **Item Limit** parameter to a high number and ensure that **"Display items in batches of the specified size"** option is selected.  See Image 2 below.

| Image 1 | Image 2 |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Creating an Indexed Column] | [image: Item Limit parameter] |

| Result |
| --- |
| [image: Result] |

Interesting fact, even though the default item limit for a new view is set to 30 and the "Display items in batches of the specified size" are the default values, the Modern Experience overrides the batch size to 100.

**Hope this helped**

*Mark as answer if this solved your issue.  Upvote if it helped you*